# Show cpu and memory utilisation of process visually

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I'm writing a script to monitor CPU and MEMORY utilization during a stability test that will run 24 hours, in the end, I want to present it in a graph or another visual tool.
To do so I collect CPU/memory usage every 5 minutes
the data file look like this:

```
  -----------------------------
  CPU(%)    SWAP     Memory(%)
  -----------------------------
  181.2     0 kB       0.4
  12.5     0 kB       0.4
  0.0     0 kB       0.4
  0.0     0 kB       0.4
  0.0     0 kB       0.4
  0.0     0 kB       0.4
```

I need help with finding out a way to visualize this data in a graph

Comment: What help do you need? What is the actual question here?

Comment: I need help with finding out a way to visualize this data in a graph. adding this to the question

Comment: Ok, so what have you done so far? At the moment, you aren't asking for help, you are asking us to do the whole thing for you. You need to think about what kind of graph, and how you would like to show it. What would the axes be? What would the values be? You could start by looking at GNUplot.

Answer (score 1):

[GNOME System Monitor](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnome-system-monitor) does exactly like what you want. Or do you want to visualise it with your own program/script?

Comment: I would like to visualize it in my own script